# GIT remote extension on Visual Studio - showing tons of unknown Changes

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am using GIT remote extensions of Visual Studio code in my local laptop and when I connect to remote host via SSH I am seeing lot of unknown changes synced to GIT and waiting to stage or discard or commit . 
most of them coming from .vscode-server hidden directory from my remote machine . I tried to exclude it with all patterns in fileWatcher and couldn't help even if after reload . I did same patterns to exclude showing those files in User , Remote and workspace all areas but no luck . Any thoughts ?

Image is below and left hand side is almost 1K files which I have no idea why it came and some of the files I stage but it keep coming .

[image: Git Remote showing changes]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try first and modify or add a .gitignore file with, as content:

```
.vscode-server/
```

Then, in your remote SSH folder repository:

```
git rm --cached -r .vscode-server/
```

That should be enough for Git to ignore the folder content, and remove those entries from changes

Comment: Sorry where do you want me to place .gitignore file ? also .vscode-folder is not a real name of the folder how it exist in remote branch . may be I am missing what is right the right step you are asking me to follow

Comment: @pauldx At the root folder of your local Git repository.

Comment: well .. there is nothing coming from local GIT repo ... my GIT is SSH'ed and connected to remote server .... look at how it is coming in my updated screenshot (added new one) ... you are right it might be coming for caching ... but there is nothing code .vscode-folder .. you mean .vscode-server ?

Comment: @pauldx Sorry, the `.vscode-folder` was a typo: `.vscode-server`. Basically, add the .gitignore where you see those changes that you do not want to see: `.gitignore` + `git rm --cached` of whatever you don't want.

Comment: Finally I get down them from 3K to 91 ... I have some filed deleted which is not removing from pane . I follow your instruction but create a .gitignore file in my linux machine inside my home directory and put below : .vscode-server/**
*.log
**.log
.vscode-server
 Reload the VScode and it works ... thanks